# How to remove folder name in url without redirecting?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, ab-testing

Is it possible to change https://example.com/ab12 to https://example.com/ but showing content from https://example.com/ab12 by editing `.htaccess` as a part of AB testing?

Comment: Why don't you change the page name `ab12` to `index.html` or `index.php` or whatever depending on the technology you are using since `index` would be treated as your homepage or root when someone visits https://example.com/ab12?

Comment: @Mathews Mathai Because it is a part of AB testing where both pages are supposed to be seen by different users, but url should be the same.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't make the page static in that case. The simplest case would-be users who are logged in and not logged in. I could easily check for the session variables and decide what to deliver to them on the same page. Like for the ones who are not logged in, I would show them the login form instead of other content. You could probably do something like that?

Comment: Only redesign of the main page is being tested. AB testing itself is not an issue. The problem is showing the same url for page A and page B. It has to be done in a way described in a title.

Comment: Well, the solution I suggested is one way to do it. You check for conditions before delivering the content. eg: `Check if session variable is set before displaying something otherwise display different content. This can be done with simple if-else condition block`. If you have different user types, I believe you may have some kind of identifier set in sessions to identify each of them which you could further use to decide what content is to be delivered. Keep one page (one URL) but use conditional blocks to deliver content.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the content of "ab12" inside of the index.html file and then it will automatically redirect to that page.